# How can I get a list of worksheets in an Excel workbook and display them in the add-in UI?

Tags: office-js, scriptlab

I'm trying to do some work in an Office JS Add-in.

I've looked at both the Script Lab and side-loading via yeoman.

I just haven't been able to find enough example code to get over the hump of learning how to work with React / Typescript on top of learning the Office and Excel API itself.

It would be really great if someone could demonstrate a simple extension of the Script Lab "List worksheets" example to put the list of sheets into the Taskpanel (add-on UI) instead of simply dumping them into console.log().

Also, one follow-up question:
My goal is to port some code from a Google Sheets App Script so we can do the same thing in Excel.  The project is specific to just one workbook and is not going to be distributed.  Is it better to do this in the real Office Add-In context and suffer side-loading it (will we really always have to run a separate node server!?) or to try to do it all in Script Lab?
I like the ease of the Script Lab route, but I worry because it has warning plastered all over it that it is for experimentation and prototyping rather than production work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At its core, an Office (web) Add-in is simply a web app -- i.e., the task pane is your canvas (UI) that contains various HTML elements, and you can update/manipulate the contents of the task pane by using JavaScript/TypeScript. Therefore, you can write output to the task pane by simply specifying the HTML element(s) that will contain the output, and then using JavaScript/TypeScript to set the value of the element(s).

For example, you could specify a `span` element within the HTML:

```
<span id="result"></span>
```

And then populate this element via the script as follows:

```
$('#result').html('This is the result!');
```

I've created a snippet that illustrates this approach for the **List Worksheets** operation. You can try the snippet yourself by using Script Lab (https://aka.ms/getscriptlab). Simply install the Script Lab add-in (free), then choose "Import" in the navigation menu, and use the following Gist URL: https://gist.github.com/kbrandl/a4a1e4da51385707863aec0ebdf296f6.

Finally, comments regarding your follow-up question:

- Script Lab is an experimental tool that you can use to learn about developing Office Add-ins; it is not an official Microsoft product, it is not supported, and it is not intended for use in production use cases.
- To use an add-in in a production use case, it's recommended that you deploy the add-in (web app) to a web server and then use any of the [available methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish) for publishing the add-in.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I do understand the example you gave.  Do you think it gets much more complicated if trying to use the fabric List component?  That is where I got pretty lost.  I couldn't figure out the right way to generate the list of sheets, temporarily store them, then hand them to the List component in the render method.

Comment: Regarding the "available methods" for publishing, our environment is just a few people each using their own individual Office 365 Personal accounts.  That means that admin center and SharePoint are out.  Two out of the three are using Macs, so I *think* that rules out the Network Share, and since it is only intended for an audience of 3, going through the extra hurdles of trying to get it published on AppSource doesn't seem very feasible.  So unless I missed something, that leaves us with just Sideloading, right?

Comment: The [Build an Excel add-in using React](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/excel-quickstart-react) quickstart should be helpful for your scenario. I'm not a React expert, but I imagine that you could create an add-in using the instructions in that quickstart, then update the HTML and Script for your add-in to contain the elements for your specific scenario.  At a minimum, the quickstart should help you understand how the various components of the app are connected to each other.

Comment: Re publishing -- there are 2 pieces: 1) the web app and 2) the manifest file.  You could deploy the web app to a web server, then update the manifest to point to the URL of the web app, and deploy the manifest file to a location that all users have access to. Each user can then load the add-in in Excel by using either the instructions for [Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/create-a-network-shared-folder-catalog-for-task-pane-and-content-add-ins) or [Mac](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/sideload-an-office-add-in-on-ipad-and-mac).

Comment: Okay, thank you again! If you are feeling super kind, please feel free to take a look at my other question, but you have already been a bright point in my day.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48489281/what-is-the-proper-order-of-loading-and-syncing-to-conditionally-delete-an-offse

Comment: Happy that I could help!