# What is the proper order of loading and syncing to conditionally delete an offset range of rows from a table?

Tags: office-js

Trying to do maintenance on a table via an add-in.  If the table has more than N rows, I want to delete all but N from the end.

I finally got it to work in Script Lab as demonstrated in this gist: https://gist.github.com/70d3d62d32d4fe8f34279ab240f7b110

but it doesn't feel like I actually understand why it is working.

1. I have to call sync, but doesn't matter if I call it before or after the delete call.
2. I thought it made sense to wrap the delete inside a `context.sync().then(()=>obj.delete);`, but that doesn't work.
3. I haven't seen samples that make a bare call to `context.sync()`, they usually call `await context.sync()`, but when I try to do that, IntelliSense says it isn't in an async function.  If I add the async keyword to that nested closure, then the script throws a runtime error saying that doesn't work and I need to manage the binding manually...

Could someone please review this code and help clarify these questions?

Comment: Ugh.. I'm definitely missing something.  Trying to use the exact same steps on my real sheet leads to the error: `Unhandled Promise rejection: The property 'rowCount' is not available. Before reading the property's value, call the load method on the containing object and call "context.sync()" on the associated request context. ; Zone: <root> ; `

Comment: Okay, I think I found why it was failing in my real script.  After I did the delete, I was attempting to manipulate another table in the same `await Excel.run()` block.  If I moved that second block of code to its own run block, then it works.  Is there some limitation to what sort of code can live in the same run block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't already done so, I'd suggest that you review [Excel JavaScript API core concepts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-core-concepts), which contains info about `Excel.run(...)`, `context.sync()`, and `load()`.

Additional comments/info:

- As described in the article, you must call `load()` before you can ***read*** properties of an object. You don't need to call `load()` if you're simply setting property values or accessing other methods off of a property. If you do need to call `load()` (because you're intending to read the properties of the object), you'll need to subsequently call `sync()` so that the `load()` instruction gets executed, before you can read the object's properties.
- As described in the article, you can queue up multiple instructions on the `context` before you call `context.sync()` to execute those instructions. In the `deleteRows()` function of your snippet, the `context.sync()` that you've prefaced with a comment isn't necessary because you can simply add the `lastThreeRows.delete()` instruction to the queue first, and then all of the instructions will be executed at once at the end of `Excel.run`. (It's best practice to explicitly call `context.sync()` at the end of an `Excel.run`, but technically you don't *have* to because any queued instructions will automatically get executed when `Excel.run` concludes.)
- If you're using TypeScript, you should always `await` the `context.sync()` (e.g., `await context.sync();`), and the function definition for the function that contains `await context.sync()` must begin with the keyword `async` (e.g., `async function foo() {...}`). Within the body of a function, you can only use the keyword `await` if the function is defined as `async`.

Here's an updated gist that you can import to and run in Script Lab: https://gist.github.com/kbrandl/74e64d74f396cbe6047b3247e3c066d7. I've updated code within the `deleteRows()` function to reflect the concepts that I've described above.

```
async function deleteRows() {
    try {
        await Excel.run(async (context) => {

            const expensesTable = context.workbook.tables.getItem("ExpensesTable")

            const bodyRows = expensesTable.getDataBodyRange().load("rowCount");

            await context.sync();

            if (bodyRows.rowCount == 7) {
                const lastThreeRows = bodyRows.getOffsetRange(4, 0).getResizedRange(-4, 0);
                lastThreeRows.delete(null);
                await context.sync();
            }
        });
    }
    catch (error) {
        OfficeHelpers.UI.notify(error);
        OfficeHelpers.Utilities.log(error);
    }
}
```